# Resize de imagens com a gem Refile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

É possivel fazer o resize, procurei na documentação e não vi nada a respeito? Colocar em diversos tamanhos. A gem carrierwave tem essa opção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara já tentou com o [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)?

Essa gem você pode fazer o upload das imagens e redimensionar para qualquer tamanho, inclusive vários tamanhos em um único upload.